# Conversion of HSPICE-model to PSPICE

Tags: ltspice, simulation, pspice, hspice

I'm new to this forum. I'm writing on my master thesis about a ISFET-curcuit-design. I found a good model for the ISFET from HSpice ("pH-ISFET-CodeNachMartinoia(1999).txt"), but I need it in PSpice. The reason is, that the company I work with, they use PSpice for every of there projects. So it's a "compatibility thing". Is there anyone who could help me with this? I'm a beginner with Spice-simulation. I already found a conversion to LTSpice ("ph-ISFET-StackFERTIG.txt"). Maybe this can help. I will also attach it.

Thank you!
Regards
Aaron

---

pH-ISFET-CodeNachMartinoia(1999).txt

```
**************************************************
FILE: ISFET MACROMODEL
***************************************************
* Behavioral macromodel for the ISFET with two
* kinds of binding sites: silanol and amine sites
* By Sergio Martinoia and Giuseppe Massobrio
* Bioelectronics Laboratory, Dept. of Biophysical and Electronic Eng.
* Via Opera Pia 11A, 16145, Genova, ITALY
* email: giaser@dibe.unige.it
* September 1998
***************************************************
* PARAMETER LIST
* General constants:
* q=electronic charge [C]
* k=Boltzmann’s constant [J/K]
* T=Absolute temperature [K]
* NAv = Avogadro’s constant [1/mole]
* ISFET geometrical parameters:
* dihp=distance between the Inner Helmholtz Plane (IHP) and the ISFET surface [m]
* dohp=distance between the Outer Helmholtz Plane (IHP) and the ISFET surface [m]
* ISFET electrochemical parameters:
* Ka=positive dissociation constant [mole/l]
* Kb=negative dissociation constant [mole/l]
* Kn=dissociation constant for amine sites [mole/l]
* N=ilssilanol (or oxide) surface site density [#/m2]
* Nnit=amine surface site density [#/m2]
* Cbulk=electrolyte concentration [1/moles]
* ep=ihpsrelative permittivity of the Inner Helmholtz layer
* ep=ohpsrelative permittivity of the Outer Helmholtz layer
* ep=wsrelative permittivity of the bulk electrolyte solution
* Reference-electrode electrochemical parameters:
* Eabs=absolute potential of the standard hydrogen electrode [V]
* Erel=potential of the ref. electrode (Ag/AgCl) relative to the hydrogen electrode [V]
* Phim=work function of the metal back contact r electronic charge [V]
* Philj=liquid-junction potential difference between the ref. solution and the electrolyte [V]
* Chieo=surface dipole potential [V]
***************************************************
.OPTION LIST ingold=0 post probe
+ absmos=1e-15 dcstep=1000 nopiv
+ absv=1e-15 relv=1e-12 absi=1e-15
+ gmindc=1e-24 itl1=1000 converge accurate
+ method=gear lvltim=2 itl5=10000 delmax=1e-15
+ dv=0.2
.PARAM
+ k=1.38e-23 T=300 eps0=8.85e-12
+ Ka=15.8 Kb=63.1e-9 Kn=1e-10
+ Nsil=3.0e18 Nnit=2.0e18
+ Cbulk=0.1
* Beginning of the sub-circuit definition
*=============================================
.SUBCKT ISFET 6 1 3 4 101
*drain | ref.el | source | bulk | pH input
+ q=1.6e-19 NAv=’6.023e23*1e3’
+ epsw=78.5 epsihp=32 epsohp=32
+ dihp=0.1n dohp=0.3n Cbulk=0.1
+ Eabs=4.7 Phim=4.7 Erel=0.200 Chieo=3e-3 Philj=1e-3
+ ET=’q/(k*T)’
+ sq=’sqrt(8*eps0*epsw* k*T)’
+ Cb=’NAv*Cbulk’
+ KK=’Ka* Kb’
+ Ch=’((eps0*epsihp*epsohp)/(epsohp*dihp+epsihp*dohp))’
+ Cd=’(sq*ET* 0.5)*sqrt(Cb)’
+ Ceq=’1/(1/Cd+1/Ch)’
Eref 1 10 VOL=’Eabs-Phim-Erel+Chieo+Philj’
Ceq 10 2 C=’1/(1/Cd+1/Ch)’
EP1 46 0 VOL=’log(KK)+4.6*V(101)’
RP1 46 0 1G
EP2 23 0 VOL=’log(Ka)+2.3*V(101)’
RP2 23 0 1G
EPH 2 10 VOL=’(q/Ceq)*(Nsil*((exp(-2*V(2,10)*ET)-exp(V(46)))/(exp(-2*V(2,10)*ET)+exp(V(23))*exp(-1*V(2,10)*ET)+exp(V(46))))+Nnit*((exp(-1*V(2,10)*ET))/(exp(-1*V(2,10)*ET)+(Kn/Ka)*exp(V(23)))))’
RpH 101 0 1K
MIS 6 2 3 4 MISFET L=18u W=804u NRS=5 NRD=5
***************************************************
.MODEL MISFET NMOS LEVEL=2
+ VTO=7.99E-01 LAMBDA=7.59E-03 RSH=3.5E+01 TOX=86E-9
+ UO=6.53E+02 TPG=0
+ UEXP=7.64E-02 NSUB=3.27E+15 NFS=1.21E+11
+ NEFF=3.88 VMAX=5.35E+04 DELTA=1.47 LD=2.91E-06
+ UCRIT=7.97E+04 XJ=6.01E-09 CJ=4.44E-4 IS=1E-11
+ CJSW=5.15E-10 PHI=5.55E-01 GAMMA=9.95E-01
+ MJ=0.395 MJSW=0.242 PB=0.585
***************************************************
.ENDS ISFET
* =============================================
* Beginning of the example circuit
XIS 100 1 0 0 200 ISFET
Vbias 1 0 DC 1.5
VpH 200 0 DC 10
Vd 110 0 DC 0.5
Vid 110 100 DC 0
.OP debug
.DC Vbias 0.0 4 0.1
.PRINT DC V(1,XIS.2) V(XIS.2,0) V(XIS.23) V(XIS.46) V(1) I(Vid)
.PROBE DC V(1,XIS.2) V(XIS.2,0) V(XIS.23) V(XIS.46) V(1) I(Vid)
.END
```

---

ph-ISFET-StackFERTIG.txt

```
**************************************************
;FILE: ISFET MACROMODEL
*****************************************************************************************************
* Behavioral macromodel for the ISFET with two
* kinds of binding sites: silanol and amine sites
* By Sergio Martinoia and Giuseppe Massobrio
* Bioelectronics Laboratory, Dept. of Biophysical and Electronics Eng.
* Via Opera Pia 11A, 16145, Genova, ITALY
* email: giaser@dibe.unige.it
* September 1998
*****************************************************************************************************
* PARAMETER LIST
* General constants:
* q = electronic charge [C]
* k = Boltzmann's constant [J/K]
* T = Absolute temperature [K]
* NAv = Avogadro's constant [1/mole]
* ISFET geometrical parameters:
* dihp = distance between the Inner Helmholtz Plane (IHP) and the ISFET surface [m]
* dohp = distance between the Outer Helmholtz Plane (OHP) and the ISFET surface [m]
* ISFET electrochemical parameters:
* Ka = positive dissociation constant [mole/1]
* Kb = negative dissociation constant [mole/1]
* Kn = dissociation constant for amine sites [mole/1]
* Nsil = silanol (or oxide) surface site density [#/m2]
* Nnit = amine surface site density [#/m2]
* Cbulk = electrolyte concentration [1/moles]
* epsihp = relative permittivity of the Inner Helmholtz layer
* epsohp = relative permittivity of the Outer Helmholtz layer
* epsw = relative permitivitty of the bulk electrolyte solution
* Reference-electrode electrochemical parameters:
* Eabs = absolute potential of the standard hydrogen electrode [V]
* Erel = potential of the ref. electrode (Ag/AgCl) relative to the hydrogen electrode [V]
* Phim = work function of the metal back contact / electronic charge [V]
* Philj = liquid-junction potential difference between the ref. solution and the electrolyte [V]
* Chieo = surface dipole potential [V]
*****************************************************************************************************
;.OPTION LIST ingold = 0 post probe
;+ absmos = 1e-15 dcstep = 1000 nopiv
;+ absv = 1e-15 relv = 1e-12 absi = 1e-15
;+ gmindc = 1e-24 itl1 = 1000 converge accurate
;+ method = gear lvltim = 2 itl5 = 1000 delmax = 1e-15
;+ dv = 0.2
;.PARAM
;+ k = 1.38e-23 T = 300 eps0 = 8.85e-12
;+ Ka = 15.8 Kb = 63.1e-9 Kn = 1e-10
;+ Nsil = 3.0e18 Nnit = 2.0e18
;+ Cbulk = 0.1
* Beginning of the sub-circuit definition
*=============================================
.SUBCKT ISFET 6 1 3 4 101 params:
*drain|ref.el|source|bulk|pH input
+ q = 1.6e-19 Nav = 6.023e23*1e3
+ epsw = 78.5 epsihp = 32 epsohp = 32
+ dihp = 0.1n dohp = 0.3n Cbulk = 0.1
+ Eabs = 4.7 Phim = 4.7 Erel = 0.200 Chieo = 3e-3 Philj = 1e-3
+ ET = q/(k*T)
+ sq = sqrt(8*eps0*epsw*k*T)
+ Cb = NAv*Cbulk
+ KK = Ka*Kb
+ Ch = ((eps0*epsihp*epsohp)/(epsohp*dihp + epsihp*dohp))
+ Cd = (sq*ET*0.5)*sqrt(Cb)
+ Ceq = 1/(1/Cd + 1/Ch)
.PARAM
+ k = 1.38e-23 T = 300 eps0 = 8.85e-12
+ Ka = 15.8 Kb = 63.1e-9 Kn = 1e-10
+ Nsil = 3.0e18 Nnit = 2.0e18
+ Cbulk = 0.1
;Eref 1 10 VOL = 'Eabs-Phim-Erel+Chieo+Philj'
Vref 1 10 {Eabs-Phim-Erel+Chieo+Philj}
Ceq 10 2 {1/(1/Cd+1/Ch)}
;EP1 46 0 VOL = 'log(KK)+4.6*V(101)'
Bp1 46 0 V=log(kk)+4.6*V(101)
;EP2 23 0 VOL = 'log(Ka)+2.3*V(101)'
Bp2 23 0 V=log(Ka)+2.3*V(101)
;EPH 2 10 VOL = '(q/Ceq)*(Nsil*((exp(-2*V(2,10)*ET)-exp(V(46)))/(exp(-2*V(2,10)*ET)+exp(V(23))*exp(-1*V(2,10)*ET)+exp(V(46))))+Nnit*((exp(-1*V(2,10)*ET))/(exp(-1*V(2,10)*ET)+(Kn/Ka)*exp(V(23)))))'
Bph 2 10 V=(q/Ceq)*(Nsil*((exp(-2*V(2,10)*ET)-exp(V(46)))/
+ (exp(-2*V(2,10)*ET)+exp(V(23))*exp(-1*V(2,10)*ET)+exp(V(46))))+
+ Nnit*((exp(-1*V(2,10)*ET))/(exp(-1*V(2,10)*ET)+(Kn/Ka)*exp(V(23)))))
RpH 101 0 1K
MIS 6 2 3 4 MISFET L = 18u W = 804u NRS = 5 NRD = 5
******************************************************************************************************
.MODEL MISFET NMOS LEVEL = 2
+ VTO = 7.99E-01 LAMBDA = 7.59E-03 RSH = 3.5E+01 TOX = 86E-9
+ UO = 6.53E+02 TPG = 0
+ UEXP = 7.64E-02 NSUB = 3.27E+15 NFS = 1.21E+11
+ NEFF = 3.88 VMAX = 5.35E+04 DELTA = 1.47 LD = 2.91E-06
+ UCRIT = 7.97E+04 XJ = 6.01E-09 CJ = 4.44E-4 IS = 1E-11
+ CJSW = 5.15E-10 PHI = 5.55E-01 GAMMA = 9.95E-01
+ MJ = 0.395 MJSW = 0.242 PB = 0.585
******************************************************************************************************
.ENDS ISFET
*=============================================
*Beginning of the example circuit
;XIS 100 1 0 0 200 ISFET
;Vbias 1 0 DC 1.5
;VpH 200 0 DC 10
;Vd 110 0 DC 0.5
;Vid 110 100 DC 0
;.OP ; debug
;.DC Vbias 0 4 0.1
;.PRINT DC V(1,XIS.2) V(XIS.2,0) V(XIS.23) V(XIS.46) V(1) I(Vid)
;.PROBE DC V(1,XIS.2) V(XIS.2,0) V(XIS.23) V(XIS.46) V(1) I(Vid)
;.END
```

Comment: Be clear on what help you need. This isn't a forum; it's a Q and A site.

Comment: Get a PSPICE modelfile so that you can see what that looks like (syntax etc.). Then change the HSpice model files to use the same syntax. Try if that works. Realize that this might simply not work. A reason could be that the MOS model uses different parameters and/or is implemented differently in HSpice and PSpice.

Comment: PSpice might not recognize the behavioural source element, `Bxxx`, so intead of those try to keep HSPICE's notation but replace `Vol=` with `Val=`. IIRC, PSpice also accepts `''` (single quotes) as a replacement for `{}`, which means "evaluate whatever is within". But if it doesn't, replace single quotes with curly braces. Some MESFET parameters might also be off, or not available, you can see this in the PSpice manual (search for `pspcref.pdf`, you should find it even with "I'm feeling lucky").

Comment: Actually, just browsing the maual now and it seems PSpice has `Bxxx` reserved for their "GASFET".